# React Native Keyboard pushes everything up , i can't control

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want only the comment input to move up when keyboard is open but everything goes up

```
export default function DetailsPage({ route, navigation }) {
  const { title, detail, degree } = route.params;
  const [comment, setComment] = useState("")
  return (
    <ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
    <View style={{ height: responsiveHeight(100), paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight }} >
    
      <ImageBackground blurRadius={0} source={require('../assets/bgg.jpg')} resizeMode="cover" >
        <View style={{ height: responsiveHeight(35), borderWidth: 1 }}>
          <View style={{ width: responsiveWidth(80), height: responsiveHeight(15), justifyContent: 'space-around', alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 40 }}>
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter-Bold', fontSize: 18 }}>Example</Text>
            <Text numberOfLines={3} style={{ fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium' }}></Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>


      <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: responsiveWidth(10), paddingVertical: responsiveWidth(10), height: responsiveHeight(65), borderWidth: 1, borderTopLeftRadius: 40, borderTopRightRadius: 40, marginTop: -responsiveHeight(10), backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
        <View style={{ height: responsiveHeight(50), borderWidth: 1 }}>
          <CommentCard></CommentCard>
        </View>
      </View>
      
      <KeyboardAvoidingView >
        <View style={{height:responsiveHeight(10),backgroundColor:'white'}}>
          <InputComp></InputComp>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      
    </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

i tried the  "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan", solution
i tried the keyboardavoidingview and keyboardVerticalOffset everywhere but couldnt find a solution
i tried scrollview with and without keyboardavoidingview

[image: this happens when its openthis is the normal page]

[image: this is the normal page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it via using external package "keyboard-sticky"
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sticky-keyboard-accessory

```
  <View style={{ height: responsiveHeight(5), backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
    <KeyboardAccessory>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', height: 30 }}>
        <Input
          containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white', width: responsiveWidth(75) }}
          style={{ height: 30, backgroundColor: 'white' }}
          value={comment}
          onChangeText={(value) => setComment(value)}
          placeholder='Yorum Öner' />
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>addComment()}>
        <View style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: 'white', width: responsiveWidth(25), alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center',color:'red',fontFamily:'Roboto-Medium' }}>
            GÖNDER
          </Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAccessory>
  </View>
```

this helps me to get the view that i want

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding these 3 thing in your code.

1. Add a KeyboardAvoidingView around the InputComp component.
2. Set the behavior property of the KeyboardAvoidingView to 'padding'.
3. Set the style property of the KeyboardAvoidingView to {height:
   responsiveHeight(10), backgroundColor: 'white'}.

   ```
   export default function DetailsPage({ route, navigation }) {
   const { title, detail, degree } = route.params;
   const [comment, setComment] = useState("")
   return (
   <ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
   <View style={{ height: responsiveHeight(100), paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight }} >
         <ImageBackground blurRadius={0} source={require('../assets/bgg.jpg')} resizeMode="cover" >
   <View style={{ height: responsiveHeight(35), borderWidth: 1 }}>
     <View style={{ width: responsiveWidth(80), height: responsiveHeight(15), justifyContent: 'space-around', alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 40 }}>
       <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter-Bold', fontSize: 18 }}>Example</Text>
       <Text numberOfLines={3} style={{ fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium' }}></Text>
     </View>
     </View>
     </ImageBackground>
     <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: responsiveWidth(10), paddingVertical: responsiveWidth(10), height: responsiveHeight(65), borderWidth: 1, borderTopLeftRadius: 40, borderTopRightRadius: 40, marginTop: -responsiveHeight(10), backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
       <View style={{ height: responsiveHeight(50), borderWidth: 1 }}>
         <CommentCard></CommentCard>
       </View>
     </View>

     <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={{height:responsiveHeight(10),backgroundColor:'white'}}>
       <InputComp></InputComp>
     </KeyboardAvoidingView>

   </View>
   </ScrollView>
   );
   }

     const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     container: {
     flex: 1,
     backgroundColor: '#fff',
     alignItems: 'center',
     justifyContent: 'center',
   },
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Go to AndroidManifest.xml file search and change below line.

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

to

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

and problem solved.